# AS3 Cast Vector to Array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, vector

```
var leaderboardRowVOs:Vector.<LeaderboardRowVO> = new Vector.<LeaderboardRowVO>();
```

goes to another part of the system as an Object, and I'm trying to cast it back to actual type

```
notification.getBody() as Vector.<LeaderboardRowVO> //throwing error
```

Comment: How do you convert the Vector to an Object?

Comment: the receiving function sendNotification(body:Object) is receiving the vector, so it automatically gets casts to it, and I'm trying to retrieve it back through notification.getBody() as Vector.<LeaderboardRowVO>

Comment: would be good to now error is thrown. Is it a null pointer exception? Try to use to case the object without as operator. The as operator makes a type check and sets the value to null when something is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of type casting in AS3:

```
// Casting
// 1: returns null if types are not compatible, 
//    returns reference otherwise
notification.getBody() as Vector.<LeaderboardRowVO>

// Converting    
// 2: throws exception if types are not compatible, 
//    returns reference otherwise
Vector.<LeaderboardRowVO>(notification.getBody())
```

Case 1 does not throw error, if you have such a behaviour, there must be an error in `notification.getBody()` method.

**EDIT:** @divillysausages made a clever comment about case 2 actually creating an object of another type. This is not the case here. This is what mostly happens for native types with one exception: the Array class. Some of the native classes have top level converting functions. Refer to [adobe livedocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html) for the complete list of them. A Vector can be instantiated this way by passing an *Array* of appropriate types to the `Vector()` function.

Comment: Isn't case 2 more creating a new Vector?

Comment: No, it isn't. (Some more symbols to allow me to post, ignore them.)

Answer (score 0):

Something else must happen to the Vector within your class because it's valid to cast a vector to Object and then back to Vector. This simple test shows it:

```
var v:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();
v.push(1);
v.push(2);

var o:Object = v as Object;

var v2:Vector.<int> = o as Vector.<int>;

trace(v2[0]); // Output "1"
trace(v2[1]); // Output "2"
```

So your problem must be somewhere else.